# how to traverse an array's contents when using each() in php, without looping

Tags: php, arrays, list, each

```
$foo1 = array("bob", "fred", "jussi", "jouni", "egon", "marliese");

$bar1 = each($foo1);
print '<pre>';
print_r($bar1);
print '</pre>';
```

The above code gives the following output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => bob
    [value] => bob
    [0] => 0
    [key] => 0
)
```

how to print other arrays that $bar1 contains? Like array for fred (in $foo1)? 
* I know that it can be done using while, list and each
* I also know that foreach makes this task lot easier

I want to know if there is any handle that i can catch hold of and get something like the following output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => fred
    [value] => fred
    [0] => 0
    [key] => 0
)
```

Comment: `each()` is to be used with the `list()` construct. If you want to walk over just the array values, then `current()` and `next()` are more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$foo1 = array("bob", "fred", "jussi", "jouni", "egon", "marliese");

next($foo1);
$bar1 = each($foo1);
print '<pre>';
print_r($bar1);
print '</pre>';
```

Generally, just move the array pointer to the desired location and call `each`.

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [1] => fred
    [value] => fred
    [0] => 0
    [key] => 0
)
```

Comment: and that will output what? OP stated their output, so should you

Comment: @brucekaushik That is because `each` also advances the pointer. If you want to get fred's array to begin with, use `next` to advance the pointer, then use `each` to get his result (which will move the pointer to "jussi"). The next time you call `each` you will get jussi's result (and the pointer will move to "jouni").

Comment: @asad, thanks it helped, i just appended your code from next($foo1) to my original code,but i am getting array for "jussi" instead of "fred", the next time i do it i am getting array for "egon" not "journi"... can you please explain how to move the array pointer exactly?

Comment: @brucekaushik I just did, see my comment above. If you want to get the array for everyone, just call `each` repeatedly; it returns an array and advances the pointer. If you want it only for one person, use `next` to advance till you get to the desired location, then use `each`.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `each()`, it returns information about the next element of the input array. So the first time it will return information about "bob", the next time it will return "fred", and so on. If you want to get to a particular element, you have to keep calling `each()` or `next()` to advance the internal pointer of the array to that point.